# Как настроить Vundle для GVim на Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, vim

Сделал всё в точности как написано в [инструкции](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/wiki/Vundle-for-Windows).
Установил Git, сделал `git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git ~/vimfiles/bundle/Vundle.vim`, скопировал в начало файла _vimrc нужный текст. Теперь при запуске Gvim выдаёт следующие ошибки:

```
Error detected while processing C:/Users/***/_vimrc:
line    4:
E117: Unknown function: vundle#begin
line    6:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
line    9:
E117: Unknown function: vundle#end
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то Vundle уже давно не обновляется и зачем его использовать мне не понятно.

Что же касается того, почему оно не работает... Ну, судя по сообщению, Vim не может найти скрипт `autoload/vundle.vim`, а ищет он его просматривая каталоги указанные в опции `:h 'runtimepath'`. Отсюда полагаю, что следующая команда была пропущена, либо стоит не там где надо (должна быть до вызова функции `vundle#begin`):

```
set rtp+=~/vimfiles/bundle/Vundle.vim
```